# Euclidian Algorithm: proof that $n_i < \frac{n_{i-2}}{2}\quad \forall i\geq 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

In the euclidian algorithm to find the greatest common denominator $\text{gcd}(n,m)$ of $n$ and $m$ ($m\leq n$) I want to prove the following:

$n_i < \frac{n_{i-2}}{2}\quad \forall i\geq 2$

where $n_i$ is defined as follows:

$n_0:=n$

$n_1:=m$

$n_i := n_{i-2} - \lfloor \frac{n_{i-2}}{n_{i-1}} \rfloor n_{i-1} = n_{i-2}  \text{ mod }n_{i-1}\quad \forall i\geq 2$

Comment: How far did you get?

Comment: Honestly I'm working with examples (very rudimentary) right now. Something along the idea that if I do n mod n, n mod (n-1), n mod (n-2), etc. the "counter" resets everytime I reach a full (integer) divisor of n, from which the first one is n/2. But I can't formalize it yet...

Comment: if $n_0  = 1234 $   and $n_1 = 763,$   what is $n_2$  and how does it compare with $\frac{n_0}{2}  \; \; \; ? \; \; $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading so many overly-complicated answers in different posts this is what I came to:

$\boxed{(1) \quad a \text{ mod } b < \frac{1}{2}a \quad \forall a,b: 0<b<a \quad}$

**Proof:**

$a \text{ mod } b <b< \underbrace{\left\lfloor \frac{a}{b} \right\rfloor}_{\geq 1} b \overset{(*)}{=} a - a \text{ mod } b\qquad (*) \text{ } a = \left\lfloor \frac{a}{b} \right\rfloor b + a \text{ mod } b \Rightarrow \left\lfloor \frac{a}{b} \right\rfloor b = a - a \text{ mod } b$

$\Longrightarrow a \text{ mod } b < a - a \text{ mod } b$

$ \Longleftrightarrow a \text{ mod } b < \frac{a}{2} \quad \blacksquare$

Now, specific for the Euclidian algorithm:

$n_i := n_{i-2}  \text{ mod }n_{i-1}\quad \forall i\geq 2$

$\Longrightarrow n_i = n_{i-2}  \text{ mod }n_{i-1} \overset{(1)}{<} \frac{n_{i-2}}{2}  \quad \forall i\geq 2$